# Concurrently does not modify NODE_ENV variable

Tags: node.js, windows, webpack

So I'm working on a project using webpack and wanted to create a script on my package.json to run both dev and production mode from there. I'm a windows user and always use [Concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently) to run multiple terminal tasks at the same time.

I set my package.json scripts like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently \"set NODE_ENV=\" \"webpack --watch\"",
    "build": "concurrently \"set NODE_ENV=production\" \"webpack\""
},
```

The output of this in the terminal is:

```
set NODE_ENV= exited with code 0
Webpack is watching the files…
...
```

So basically webpack is working properly, but the variable is not being created/deleted. Both commands are failing.

If I run directly

```
set NODE_ENV=production
```

it works, so I'm a bit confused...

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Which command is it failing on, build or start?  Also, one could argue that your environment variables should be set in the environment, rather than as part of the mom scripts.  Have a read of 12factor.net.

Comment: Both of them are failing. Thanks for the read, I'll give it a go right away.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
"start": "concurrently \"set NODE_ENV=\" \"webpack --watch\"",
"build": "concurrently \"set NODE_ENV=production\" \"webpack\""
```

to:

```
"start": "NODE_ENV= webpack --watch",
"build": "NODE_ENV=production webpack"
```

You cannot change the environment in one process and expect it to be changed in another started in parallel. You can only change the env of child processes and only on their startup. Child process always inherits the environment from the parent.

If the above doesn't work on Windows then use `cross-env`:

```
npm install --save-dev cross-env
```

and in package.json use:

```
"start": "cross-env NODE_ENV= webpack --watch",
"build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack"
```

Comment: I haven't done Node on Windows yet, is that syntax going to set the environment variables?

Comment: @Paul See my updated answer for setting the environment on Windows in case the first example fail.

Comment: @rsp Well it looks like any of those work... The first solution do not set the enviroment, and the second (using cross-env) does not do anything at all -neither setting the env variable or runing webpack-. Thanks anyways for taking your time.

Comment: you shouldn't remove concurrently, it wasn't part of the problem